# Angular Child Routing in Tabs not showing in active tab

Tags: angular, routes, parent-child

Hi I am using angular tabs to route my application and I have some child routes. The second tab has two child routes. When I switch to the second child route the tab status goes from active to nothing. I don't know where I could be going wrong. My code so far is as follows:

**content.html (for the nav links)**

```
 <nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="center">
        <a mat-tab-link
           *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
           [routerLink]="link.path"
           routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
           [active]="rla.isActive">
          {{link.label}}
        </a>
      </nav>
```

**Content.ts**

```
  navLinks = [
    {path: 'details', label: 'Details'},
    {path: 'select/products', label: 'Product'},
    {path: 'client', label: 'Client'},
  ];
```

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent },
  { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },
  { path: 'warranty',component: WarrantyComponent },
  { path: 'details',component: CldetailsComponent },
  { path: 'select',component: SelectComponent },
];

RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } 
    ),

RouterModule.forRoot([
     { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
     { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
     { 
       path: 'policy', 
       component: PolicyComponent, 
       children: [
        {path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent}, 
        {path: 'select',component: SelectComponent, children: [{path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent},{path: 'warranty', component: WarrantyComponent},]}, 
        {path: 'client', component: CldetailsComponent},
       ]
    },
```

**Router Links paths I am using for the nav**

```
<a routerLink="/policy/select/products"></a>
<a routerLink="/policy/select/warranty"></a>
```

Screenshots below show, when using the product route it's fine but when I try to route to the warranty route, the tab state goes. Any ideas?

[image: Active state]

[image: Not Active state]

Comment: Where is your `warranty` route has been defined ?

Comment: @SunilSingh Apologies I have edited the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the parent nav link path. You should use the `parent` path of product and warranty in the navbar so that it can be active on the bases of `product` and `warranty.

Change the path for `select/products` to `select` as

```
  navLinks = [
    {path: 'details', label: 'Details'},
    {path: 'select', label: 'Product'}, //<--- changed here
    {path: 'client', label: 'Client'},
  ];
```

Note : You may need to change the routing configuration for `select` path as well. What needs to be the default Component to be rendered in case of `/policy/select` path.

Ex : here the default Component will be `ProductComponent`

```
 children: [

        {path: 'select',component: SelectComponent, children: [{path: '', component: ProductsComponent}, {path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent},{path: 'warranty', component: WarrantyComponent}]}
       ]
```

Comment: That didn't work, it just removes the active state on all the tabs

Comment: Change in the navLinks as mentioned in the answer.